# Import widgets into a function from a class in another file. NameError: name 'textbox1' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, import, python-import

In the `function1` function of the `main.py` file, i would like to import `textbox1` and `textbox2` from the `Page1(tk.Frame)` class of the `page1.py` file.

I get the error `NameError: name 'textbox1' is not defined`, because `textbox1` and `textbox2` are not imported correctly. This is the code I'm using. What am I doing wrong? How to solve?

**main.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

from page1 import Page1

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('480x320')

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('default') 
style.configure('TNotebook', tabposition='wn', background='white', tabmargins=0)
style.configure('TNotebook.Tab', background='white', width=10, focuscolor='yellow', borderwidth=0)
style.map('TNotebook.Tab', background=[('selected', 'yellow')])

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.place(x=0, y=70)
page1 = Page1(nb, width=492, height=905)
nb.add(page1, text='Tab 1', compound='left')

def function1(textbox1, textbox2):

    val_1 = "example 1"
    textbox1.insert(0, val_1)

    val_2 = "example 1"
    textbox2.insert(0, val_2)

button1 = Button(root, text="Button", command= function1(textbox1, textbox2))
button1.place(x=0, y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

**page1.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import ttk

class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

        self.textbox1 = ttk.Entry(self, width=7)
        self.textbox1.place(x=10, y=10)

        self.textbox2 = ttk.Entry(self, width=7)
        self.textbox2.place(x=10, y=40)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my knowledge, to access `textbox1 and textbox2` in the function1 function in `main.py`, you should make them instance variables by using `self.textbox1` and `self.textbox2`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

        self.textbox1 = ttk.Entry(self, width=7)
        self.textbox1.place(x=10, y=10)

        self.textbox2 = ttk.Entry(self, width=7)
        self.textbox2.place(x=10, y=40)
```

And `main.py`  should be something like this

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from page1 import Page1


def function1():
    val_1 = "example 1"
    page1.textbox1.delete(0, tk.END)  # Clear any existing text
    page1.textbox1.insert(0, val_1)

    val_2 = "example 2"
    page1.textbox2.delete(0, tk.END)  # Clear any existing text
    page1.textbox2.insert(0, val_2)

button1 = Button(root, text="Button", command=function1)
button1.place(x=0, y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

This should possibly solve the issue.Can you try and hope this helps.

**Note** : If you just want to edit you script.

you can add this line for button, where `page1` object is used

```
button1 = Button(root, text="Button", command= function1(page1.textbox1, page1.textbox2))
```

I have tested and its working good for me :

[image]

Comment: I'm testing. Give me some minutes. Thank you

Comment: `button1 = Button(root, text="Button", command= function1(page1.textbox1, page1.textbox2))` -  if not you can add this in your and it should work